# Android Studio Flutter project can not recognize GradleException and Properties in build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I hope there is a solution to this coz Google did not help much
Android Studio Flutter project can not recognize GradleException and Properties in build.gradle

Steps to reproduce:

1. New flutter project in Android studio
2. Navigate to /android/app/src/build.gradle
3. Error reported: Cannot resolve symbol 'GradleException' and Cannot resolve symbol 'Properties'

[image]

Comment: No need to worry about this. You can still build your flutter app.

Comment: Thanks, Abhishek for the confidence but it would be nice if they could get rid of this annoying quirk :)

Answer (score 0):

You can juste remove the **new** in front of *Properties* and *GradleException*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).